# MySQL Foreign Keybut Query

Tags: mysql, indexing, key

I have a column that's a foreign key. Adding rows to the column is fine as long as it the row I'm adding has data that is present in the parent table. Although, some rows don't have an entry that belongs in the parent table. I'd like to keep the column with a foreign key but even if it doesn't have a parent, the column should still store it.

Are there any ways to do this within MySQL?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key constraint enforces that the value exists in the referenced table. If you try to insert a value that doesn't exist in the referenced table then it will fail.

You have two options:

1. Store NULL instead of the ID that doesn't exist.
2. Don't use a foreign key constraint.